# Selecionar todos meses do ano no postgres

Tags: postgresql

Salve galera,

tenho o seguinte select:

```
select sum(valor) valor, extract (month from datahorainicio) from agendamento where extract (year from datahorainicio)= 2020 and status='CONCLUIDO' and id_barbearia=1 group by extract(month from datahorainicio)
```

Ele me retorna a soma dos valores referentes aos serviços prestados em um mês.

Gostaria de saber como retornar todos os meses do ano no select, mesmo tendo mês em que não haja nenhum valor. Preciso disso para poder preencher um gráfico no front com os meses e tals.

Comment: Poderia adicionar a estrutura da tabela do banco?

Answer (score -1):

A função generate_series juntamente com LEFT OUTER JOIN pode ser de grande utilidade:

```
SELECT foo.data, COALESCE(SUM(valor), 0) valor FROM generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, '2020-31-12'::date, '1 month') AS foo(data)
LEFT OUTER JOIN agendamento 
WHERE data_trunc(datahorainicio, 'day')= foo.data AND status='CONCLUIDO' AND id_barbearia=1 
GROUP BY foo.data;
```